# Presenting/dismissing modal view controller with custom animations does not display presenting view controller underneath

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have implemented a view controller which provides a navigation structure similar to UINavigationController. It is using view controller containment. All view controllers are added as children.

When I present a modal view controller from a view controller within this navigational flow, the underlying view disappears during the custom transition and the user is left viewing the Window view below.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{

    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.4, 0.4);
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

This is a very jarring experience. Previously this animation would shrink the modal view controller's view and fade it into the presenting view controller's view underneath. As I stated before, now the user is exposed to the view of the Window (which currently has not had an color values set).

Refering to the View Controller documentation I feel as though I have set all the right fields, however, something is incorrect.

> A view controller presents another view controller when it wants that
>   view controller to perform a task. The presenting view controller is
>   in charge of this behavior. It configures the presented view
>   controller, receives information from it, and eventually dismisses it.
>   However, while it is being presented, the presented view controller’s
>   view is temporarily added to the window’s view hierarchy.

My presenting view controller is my custom navigation controller, the presented view controller is a modal view controller that allows the user to compose a conversation.  My application's window root view controller is correctly configured to my custom navigation controller.

I also read some more about presentation context and have configured my custom navigation controller as having definesPresentationContext as YES.

> When a view controller is presented, the portion of the screen that it
>   covers is defined by a presentation context provided to it by another
>   view controller. The view controller that provides the presentation
>   context does not need be the same view controller that presented it.
>   Figure 1-15 shows the same view controller hierarchy that is presented
>   in Figure 1-14. You can see that the content view presented the view
>   controller, but it did not provide the presentation context. Instead,
>   the view controller was presented by the tab controller. Because of
>   this, even though the presenting view controller only covers the
>   portion of the screen provided to it by the tab view controller, the
>   presented view controller uses the entire area owned by the tab view
>   controller. Within my custom navigation controller I have not
>   overriden any methods related to presentation or dismissal of view
>   controllers. All of the child view controllers that are added are all
>   added as childViewControllers and their views have been added to this
>   custom navigation controller.

- Why would a custom transition show the Window's view instead of
  respecting the custom containment view controller which provides the
  presentation context?
- Why would the traditional transition animations    work as expected?